# mTLS on Heroku with Rails

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, nginx-reverse-proxy, heroku

We currently host on Heroku and we need to implement mTLS in front of our Rails app. What is a good strategy to achieve this?

It seems like we need reverse proxy which knows how to deal with mTLS. Probably nginx or
https://github.com/PaloAltoNetworks/mtlsproxy

Would it be possible to run both proxy and rails same server instance (this would be the most secure way to do it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to do it is via Cloudflare proxy (SSL > Client Certificates).

https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/client-certificates/enable-mtls/

For custom configuration you can setup custom server with Nginx on it + reverse proxy which will point to your localhost:3000 or to another server.